# Compression of short sequences of 16-bit integers

Tags: arrays, integer, compression, lossless-compression

I have to compress a set of 8 lists of 9 16-bit signed integers, e.g.:

a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

b = [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]

c = [19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27]

d = [28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38]

e = ...

We don't have control on the numbers source, but I did some analysis and we saw that usually between 12-18% of the numbers are 0s, and 85-90% of them can be represented with 4 bits or less. About 99% can be represent with 8 bits. Numbers are equally distributed around 0.

The data are going to be packed into a shared fixed size structure, that means that in the end we will have

sizeof(a_compressed)==sizeof(b_compressed)==sizeof(c_compressed)==sizeof(d_compressed)=...

that makes the worst case dominating

Each list has to be independent from the others (e.g. I must not need access to a in order to read b) but they can (optionally) share extra information in an independent, shared data structure x.

The computational cost of compression is irrelevant. For decompression, it is not a critical parameter, but would be appreciated if not the entire list has to be read in order to decompress it. Data access is known to be sequential (we are going to read c[0], then c[1], c[2]...)

So far, best result I got has been obtained with this algorithm:
 - Look for highest absolute value of the 4 arrays
 - Get number of bits necessary to represent it
 - Encode all the numbers with this bit precision
 - Store the bit precision for successive decompression

As result, we got a worst case in our dataset of 53.5 bits/list

I hope I provided enough information...Thanks!

Comment: You could make some static Huffman tree that fits the distribution (or range coding or ANS) but I'm not sure how to interpret your preference for not having the read the whole list. With variable-length encoding you typically have to decode from the start, but these lists are extremely short.. is that acceptable?

Comment: Is it fine if I have to read them from the start - the "whole list read" constraint means that I dont have to wait to read the last entry of the compressed list to be able to decode the first one

Comment: Update: I tried storing for each index of the list the number of bits of the longest of the block (e.g: 4 bits for a[0],b[0],c[0],d[0], 7 bits for a[1],b[1],...).


Using this system I got 50.5 bits/list.
I tried ANS but or the algorithm is not fit for this task or I'm implementing it wrongly since I got 108.04 bits/list.